# Enum DependencyProperty passed as Int from Setter

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I encountered this strange behavior, I have a UserControl with a CommandPosition DependencyProperty that accept an enum called "Position" declared inside the class* as:

```
public enum Position
{
    Left,
    Right,
    Both
}
```

*Inside or outside it's irrelevant in this situation, I tried both.

The control moves some button around based on the defined Position.
This is the property declaration, seems fine with me:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandPositionProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CommandPosition", typeof(Position), typeof(PoisonControl), new PropertyMetadata(Position.Right, OnPositionChanged));

private static void OnPositionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue is Position)
        ((PoisonControl)d).CommandPosition = (Position)e.NewValue;
}
```

Inside the View, I correctly define my control and can set CommandPosition="Left" (and get Intellisense) without any problem, the OnPositionChanged method is called and a Position is passed to e.NewValue as expected.

Now I need to change the position based on ViewState size, inside the ViewState.Setters I have this line:

```
<Setter Target="Poison.CommandPosition" Value="Both" />
```

It kinda works, OnPositionChanged method is called, but the type of e.NewValue is System.Int32 (in this case 2) while e.OldValue is still Position (in this case 0).

Why? Am I doing something wrong?
I could make it work by casting the underlying type to Position, but I'd prefer not to and understand this strange behavior.

Comment: I don't think it is strange. In C# `enum`'s are represented as integers by default.

Comment: It is, because only when passed by the Setter it's passed as Int32.

Comment: Just a note, instead of `e.NewValue.GetType() == typeof(Position)` you could better write `e.NewValue is Position`. Besides that, when the `OnPositionChanged` handler isn't used for any other property, there is no need to check the type of `e.NewValue` at all. You can *always* safely cast it to your enum type, like `(Position)e.NewValue`.

Comment: Yeah, I know... it's just an old habit.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] it's impractical to spend time trying to reproduce the issue. But have you tried `Value="{x:Static l:Position.Both}"`? (Where `l` is an XML namespace declared appropriately, of course). It's possible that using `"Both"` on its own causes the string to go through a UWP converter that doesn't bother to generate the exact enum type object. You should get the right type when you're explicit about the type of the value being set.

Comment: I'd love to try your suggestion, but x:Static doesn't exists in UWP... :( I'll check if there is something similar.

Comment: This may be potential issue with `Setter` in UWP. If we set `CommandPosition` with `Setter` in `Style` and use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(GetValue(CommandPositionProperty).GetType().ToString());` in `CommandPosition`'s getter, we will find its type is also `System.Int32`. However this won't be a serious problem. OldValue and NewValue come untyped. Usually we will always do a cast when using them.